# Datetime select define hours range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm using a datetime to save some appointments in a calendar.
In this way I can store togheter date and time without have the two values distinct.

What I'd like is to allow users to edit the appointment and change date/time.
The fact is that I cannot leave the user free to select any hour but any appointment must be set in a predefined range of hours (24h format: 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20).

Since in the documentation I could not find any way to customize `datetime_select` I'm actually using the following form:

```
.control-group
  = f.label :start_at, :class => 'control-label'
  .controls
    = f.date_select :start_at, :value => f.object.start_at, :class => "datetimefield"
.control-group
  = f.label :start_at, :class => 'control-label'
  .controls
    = f.select :start_at, :value => Event::ALLOWED_HOURS, :class => 'number_field'
```

`Event::ALLOWED_HOURS` is an array containing the hours I want to let users choose from.
When submitting this form the update action loses the timing info, resulting in a datetime like: `2012-05-18 00:00:00` instead of using the hour defined in my select.

What can I do to make this work as I need?

This is the controller, please note that this is a nested resource of `EventCalendar`:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  # GET /events
  # GET /events.json
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @events }
    end
  end

  # GET /events/1
  # GET /events/1.json
  def show
    @event_calendar = EventCalendar.find(params[:event_calendar_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @event }
    end
  end

  # GET /events/new
  # GET /events/new.json
  def new
    @event_calendar = EventCalendar.find(params[:event_calendar_id])
    @start_at = Time.parse("#{params[:day]} #{params[:hour]}")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @event }
    end
  end

  # GET /events/1/edit
  def edit
    @event_calendar = EventCalendar.find(params[:event_calendar_id])
  end

  # POST /events
  # POST /events.json
  def create
    @event_calendar = EventCalendar.find(params[:event_calendar_id])
    @start_at = params[:start_at]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Appuntamento creato con successo.' }
        format.json { render json: @event = EventCalendar.find(params[:event_calendar_id]), status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /events/1
  # PUT /events/1.json
  def update
    @event_calendar = EventCalendar.find(params[:event_calendar_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Appuntamento aggiornato con successo.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /events/1
  # DELETE /events/1.json
  def destroy
    @event_calendar = EventCalendar.find(params[:event_calendar_id])
    @event.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Appuntamento cancellato con successo.'}
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post your controller code that handles this form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to David suggestion I would create a virtual attribute `start_at_hours` then instead of putting the line inside the controller just edit the Model `Event` defining a `before_update` callback as:

```
# inside your model
before_update :set_hour

def start_at_hours
  if !self.start_at.blank?
    self.start_at.hour
  end
end

def start_at_hours=(value)
end

# model code ...
private
def set_hour
  self.start_at = Time.parse(self.start_at.to_s) + self.start_at_hours.to_i.hours
end
```

This should work as you need without exceptions.
It's doing the same thing as David explanation, but directly in the model without the need to change your controller.

Edit: by defining a getter and a setter you can also set the default value for your select (the setter is not needed in this case, but I put it anyway).

Comment: It works fine! But only if I declare the virtual attribute as an `attr_accessor`.

Comment: Good answer! Definitely an improvement over mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem: Your create (and update) method aren't looking at the hours field when creating the `@start_at` variable. Try the following, it should work:

```
.control-group
  = f.label :start_at, :class => 'control-label'
  .controls
    = f.date_select :start_at, :value => f.object.start_at, :class => "datetimefield"
.control-group
  = f.label :start_at, :class => 'control-label'
  .controls
    = f.select "start_at_hours", :value => Event::ALLOWED_HOURS, :class => 'number_field'
```

And in the update method on your controller:

```
# PUT /events/1
# PUT /events/1.json
  def update
    @event_calendar = EventCalendar.find(params[:event_calendar_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      params[:start_at] = Time.parse(params[:start_at]) + params[:start_at_hours].to_i.hours
      if @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Appuntamento aggiornato con successo.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The key line is this one:

```
params[:start_at] = Time.parse(params[:start_at]) + params[:start_at_hours].to_i.hours
```

It's replacing the `start_at` param (which only contains the date) with a new Time object that has the extra hours included.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I put that line in my code, then I created a virtual attribute `start_at_hours`, but when submitting the form I get `can't convert nil into String` referred to `line #63` that is the line you say. I tried calling explicitly `.to_s` on `params[:start_at]` but then it says `no time information in ""`.

Comment: Something weird's happening with your form then. From what I can tell it should be populating the `:starts_at` param from the date select.

Comment: `starts_at` is an array because each value is something like `starts_at(1i)`, `starts_at(2i)`, `starts_at(3i)` since the `date_field` creates 3 distinct selects. May be this the cause? I should try joining the values...